# Calling grunt.config.set inside grunt.util.spawn doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, spawn

I'm trying to set the current Git SHA in my project's Grunt configuration, but when I try to access it from another task it isn't available, What am I missing?

```
grunt.registerTask('sha', function () {
  var done   = this.async();

  grunt.util.spawn({
    cmd: 'git',
    args: ['rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD']
  }, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
      grunt.fail.fatal(err);
    } else {
      grunt.config.set('git', {sha: res.stdout});
      if (grunt.option('debug') || grunt.option('verbose')) {
        console.log("[sha]:", res.stdout);
      }
    }
    done();
  });
});
```

After running the task, I expect the config to be available in another task configuration:

```
requirejs: {
  dist: {
    ...
    out: '<%= app.dist %>/scripts/module_name.<%= git.sha %>.js'
    ...
  }
}
```

**So... What's the problem?**

The problem is that Require JS is writing to the file `public/scripts/module_name..js`, the SHA is not available in the configuration (when the filename should be `public/scripts/module_name.d34dc0d3.js`).

**UPDATE:**

The problem is that I'm running `requirejs` tasks with `grunt-concurrent`, so the Grunt configuration is not available for `requirejs`.

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
  ...
  'getsha',
  'concurrent:dist',
  ...
]);
```

And the concurrent task, looks like:

```
concurrent: {
  dist: [
    ...
    'requirejs',
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem *in* the code you are showing us.

Comment: Hi Louis, the problem is that `requirejs` is generating a file with the name: `public/scripts/module_name..js` where it should be: `public/scripts/module_name.DEADC0DE.js`

Comment: How are you running the tasks? Is `requirejs` being spawned as well? If so it won't have access to the grunt config you've set in the parent process.

Comment: Ah, thanks @KyleRobinsonYoung your question made me realize what I'm doing wrong. My `build` task runs several others... BUT the `requirejs` task is executed via Grunt `concurrent` task. Now I know what's the problem, *but still dunno how to solve it! Any ideas?*

Comment: @IvanTorres Sorry, I used ambiguous language. What I meant is that I did not see the cause (which I called "the problem") of the issue you encountered. I realize now that "the problem" could be understood to refer either to the cause or the effect. Maybe someone will know what to do but I'd have to see more of the Gruntfile to figure it out. (I had not see the latest edit when I started writing this comment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `grunt-concurrent` will spawn tasks in child processes, they do not have access to the context of the parent process. Which is why doing `grunt.config.set()` within the parent context is not available in the config of the child context.

Some of the solutions to make the change available in the child context are:

**Write the data to the file system**
Write the data to a temporary file with `grunt.file.write('./tmp/gitsha', res.stdout)` and then have the task being ran in a child process read the temporary file:

```
out: (function() {
  var out = grunt.config('app.dist') + '/scripts/module_name.';
  if (grunt.file.exists('./tmp/gitsha')) {
    out += grunt.file.read('./tmp/gitsha');
  } else {
    out += 'unknown';
  }
  return out + '.js';
}())
```

**Use a socket**
This is a very convoluted solution but a solution nonetheless. See the net node docs: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener on creating a server on the parent process then have the child process connect to the socket for the data.

Or check out https://github.com/shama/blackbox for a library that makes this method a bit simpler.

**Fork the parent process instead of spawn/exec**
Another method is to use fork: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options instead of grunt-concurrent. Fork lets you send messages to child processes with `child.send('gitsha')` and receive them in the child with `process.on('message', function(gitsha) {})`

This method also can get very convoluted.

**Use a proxy task**
Have your sha task set the config as you're currently doing:

```
grunt.registerTask('sha', function() {
  grunt.config.set('git', { sha: '1234' });
});
```

Change your concurrent config to call a proxy task with the sha:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concurrent: {
    dist: [
      'proxy:requirejs:<%= git.sha %>'
    ]
  }
});
```

Then create a proxy task that runs a task with setting the passed value first:

```
grunt.registerTask('proxy', function(task, gitsha) {
  grunt.config.set('git', { sha: gitsha });
  grunt.task.run(task);
});
```

The above can be simplified to set values specifically on requirejs but just shown here as a generic example that can be applied with any task.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response @KyleRobinsonYoung, I'm gonna go with the proxy tag, great idea!